# Can't show PHP file result in HTML

Tags: php, html

Good afternoon,

So I met a problem, I can't display PHP file results in HTML.

As example I have php file named `hi.php` that contains code like this:

```
<?PHP
$hi="Hello!";
echo "$hi";
?>
```

And I have `index.html` that contains body like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php include "taskai.php" ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And I get a blank page... No results displayed from `hi.php`. I'm working on localhost, xampp. May this be the problem, or I have something wrong?

Comment: Good afternoon, Tomas. By default, HTML files doesn't load php commands: try to rename it in `index.php`

Comment: Do you really get a *blank* page?  What do you see when you view the page *source* in the web browser?

Comment: as @fusion3k said, if your file ends with `.html` then any PHP in it will not work. However, the `hi.php` code should work by itself. What is your URL like when running `hi.php`?

Comment: _And I get a blank page_...If it's true then might be something wrong in `php.ini`

Comment: why are you showing this `taskai.php` in your code? is that relevant?

Comment: @fusion3k, that worked well. But what should I do to echo result in HTML ? :)

Comment: you have to use [`include("taskai.php")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) instead of [`show_source("taskai.php")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php)

Comment: @david, in code I get my query as a comment `<!--?php include "taskai.php" ?-->` 

@CodeGodie, the point is to show something from php file in HTML file :) I will use `include filename` because I need to display the result only

Comment: you need to instruct your system to treat `.html` files as PHP if you haven't already. If not, then give it the `.php` extension. You running this off a webserver or not?

Comment: @TomasVilemaitis: Then clearly the PHP code isn't being evaluated.  Which by default doesn't happen in `.html` files.  You can rename it to `.php`, or you can configure your server to process `.html` files with PHP.  (The former option is preferred, as the latter creates unnecessary overhead for HTML files.)

Comment: and if local, you accessing as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `file:///file.xxx`? Two different animals here.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answers guys! Solution is to change `index.html` to `index.php` or move to webserver :-)) Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

- your HTML file should have the `.php` extension for it to understand PHP code
  change `index.html` to `index.php`
- you are not using `include` to include the code onto your HTML

  Do it this way:

  **index.php**

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <body>
       <?php 
       include "taskai.php" 
       ?>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `index.php` with that content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$hi="Hello!";
echo "$hi";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

That should give you an idea of how things work.

---

There obviously are endless variants. For example you can also do this:

File `index.php`:

```
<?php
$hi="Hello!";

echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
{$hi}
</body>
</html>
EOT;
```